# Simple/Naive Implementation of Identity and Maybe Monad in Elixir

Tags: monads, elixir, optional

This is my first crack at a identity monad and a maybe monad in Elixir:

```
defmodule Monad do
  @doc "v is value to be wrapped as monadic value"                          
  def return(v), do: fn -> v end
  @doc "m is monad function, mv is monadic value"
  def bind(m, mv), do: m.(mv.())
end

#Simple identity monad
id = fn s -> s end
h = Monad.return(:ok)
r = Monad.bind(id, h)

#Maybe monad
maybe = fn s -> if is_nil(s), do: :error, else: s end
r = Monad.bind(maybe, h)
```

I'd like to see if there is a way to make the monad into a protocol since the return and bind seem to be common to all monads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're sort of missing the point with this code - the difference between different kinds of monads (Maybe vs. List vs. Identity, etc.) is in the different implementations of `return` and `bind`. I think a good starting place might be reading through a library that implements monads in elixir, like [monad](https://github.com/rmies/monad/tree/develop/lib/monad). Looking into that you can see that for example `Maybe` is implemented like this (simplifying):

```
def return(x), do: {:just, x}

def bind({:just, x}, f), do: f.(x)
def bind(:nothing, _), do: :nothing

def fail(_), do: :nothing
```

While  for example `Error` (the second-simplest I think) is implemented like this:

```
def return(x), do: {:ok, x}

def bind(e = {:error, _}, _), do: e
def bind({:ok, x}, f), do: f.(x)

def fail(msg), do: {:error, msg}
```

The difference between the two being that in one case you only get information that there is no result (`:nothing`) while in the other you either get a result or some information on the error (represented by `{:error, _}`). Also note that both have additional helper functions to for example extract the result (presumably at the end of the computation).

Comment: I'm trying to follow your comments. You're saying I should make the code _less_ generic?  I understand that I might change the return function to get different behavior there but the bind can be easily parameterized by the function which is passed in so I'm not sure I understand how making it less generic is an improvement.

Comment: Again - `bind` should be implemented differently, depending on the type of monad you are using. The function `f` passed to `bind` on the other hand is part of the user's logic. For example `find_user |> bind(&authenticate_user/1) |> bind(&render_response/1)` - assuming this is the maybe monad you'd expect `find_user`, `authenticate_user`, `render_response` to be functions provided by the user of your monad API and returning `{:just, _}` or `:nothing`.

Comment: Also check out [MonadEx](https://github.com/rob-brown/MonadEx).